# why the swap partition is not working

Tags: encryption, swap

i have setup fully encrypted lvm on my laptop,it have created a swap partition also.But why system does not recognize the swap partition?
here is the screenshot link
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/P801g.png]

Comment: Is swap mentioned in /etc/fstab?  Can you manually run: swapon /dev/ubuntu-vg/swap_1

Answer (score 0):

How do you know it does not recognize swap? According to the right part of your screenshot the system does know there's swap. According to the memory stats in the left part of your screenshot you use about 57% of your memory so about 43% is still free. This is apparently enough so the system has no need to use swap right now.